# border visibility controlling

Tags: apache-flex

I want to know if I can control the border visibility of canvas. and other components.

I mean can I enable the border in specific place and disable it in others.

In my task I want to show the border around my canvases except the intersections between them

Comment: I assume you can do this with a mix of borderSkin and borderStyle http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#style:borderStyle and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#style:borderSkin . What have you tried?  And why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flex 4 and bordercontainer you can simply achieve it by setting the property "borderVisible" to either true or false. If you are using Flex 3 and canvas there is no golden bullet but you can always skin it or create you own custom component so that you can use them in future.